# Problema na conexão do banco de dados

Tags: java, sql, banco-de-dados

Meu grupo estamos fazendo um projeto de Java com banco de dados e ao continuar o projeto em outras máquinas apenas apareceu problemas somente no meu que está dando o seguinte erro ao tentar fazer a conexão com o banco de dados:

```
Não é possível estabelecer conexão. 
Não é possível estabelecer uma conexão com 
  jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample usando
  org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver (
    org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver starting from
    ModuleCL@38dbfa6c[org.netbeans.modules.db] with 
    possible defining loaders null and declared parents  [
      ModuleCL@7f35b22c[org.openide.io],
      ModuleCL@4f215e3f[org.openide.nodes],
      ModuleCL@2e2df564[org.netbeans.core.ide],
      org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@377dca04,
      ModuleCL@447a5b33[org.openide.windows],
      ModuleCL@7887f48c[org.netbeans.modules.keyring],
      ModuleCL@69f02588[org.netbeans.modules.db.metadata.model],
      ModuleCL@25df2cfa[org.netbeans.modules.javahelp],
      ModuleCL@4621b284[org.openide.explorer],
      ModuleCL@6eeca476[org.openide.loaders],
      ...6 more
   ]
).
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Verifique a string de conexão. Pode ser isso. tente: "jdbc:derby://localhost\\sample;databaseName=<>nome_banco>;user=<usuário>;password=<>senha";

Comment: Tentei e também não deu certo. O projeto está certo, só está dando erro nesta máquina nos outros é só abrir o projeto com dois cliques e já faz a conexão.

Comment: Normalmente é necessário adicionar variáveis de ambiente para o java funcionar. Sou iniciante em Java, mas se você puder dê uma olhada se está informado o JAVA_HOME, e se a instalação do java no PATH está informado também